# dynamic links using php

Tags: php

i have this code snippet tha loops through an xml file and outputs the name and sector values 
in the file onto a livtview. this is the format of xml:

```
<searches>
<search id ='1234'>
<name> somename </name>
<address> some address </address>
<sector> some sector </sector>
<contacts> 12345, me@me.com </contacts>
<searches>
```

this is the loop:

```
<div>

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset     ui-corner-all ui-shadow">

<?php foreach($objj as $searches): ?> 
<li><a href="" data-role="button"> <?php echo $searches -> name) ?></a></li>  

<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any time the a button is clicked, i want the rest of the information (ie. contact and address) of only that link to be echoed to the user... Please help. any link is welcome...

the js solution is good but its a mobile web and i guess the screen size will not help and moreso when the results of that user is pasted on the next page the result will be sent to others by email or sms and also shared on facebook so i think i will go in for php solution but i think am not getting the explanation on the php solution can you please elaborate?

Comment: I assume you mean you want to use javascript to show/hide the values in the user interface?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this: client side using Javascript (I used jQuery) or server side using only PHP.

**jQuery Solution**

Put all of the user's information in a div in the `li` element. Then you can use some JS to toggle the visibility of those elements.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="people">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">sachleen</a>
        <div>More info for sachleen here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-role="button">bob</a>
        <div>More info for bob here</div>
    </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#people li div { display: none; }​
```

**jQuery**

```
​$("#people li > a​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div").toggle();
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dfPU6/)

---

**The php-only solution**

You'll want to link the names to a page that will show more information. Something like:

```
<a href="moreinfo.php?user=<?php echo $searches -> name) ?>" data-role="button"> <?php echo $searches -> name) ?></a>
```

But you might want to use an ID or something else instead of just the name.

Then on that page, you use `$_GET['user']` and reads the data for that user and displays it on the page.

Personally, I'd go with the JS solution.